# Sheet copying moving blank or error

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013

> Microsoft Excel 2013 (15.0.4675.1000) 32bit

When trying to move or copy one of my sheet no matter in same workbook or other I get empty sheet which named as Sheet1 Sheet2 and etc.

When trying do the same thing programmatically with VBA like:

```
Sheets("Invoice").Select
Sheets("Invoice").Copy Before:=Sheets(1)
```

I also get error `Run time Error 1004: Method Copy of class Worksheet failed`
This happens very often and every time on different sheets.

Maybe it because of many defined ranges on the sheet?

I tried save and close the workbook after copying but suck.
Workbook size is 100Kb only.

After empty sheet is created if I try to remove it Excel going to stop working and crashing.

Is this a Excel bug or what?

[Here is attached file](https://www.sendspace.com/file/w6vlh4)

Can you duplicate Invoice sheets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think 'bug' is probably fair in this case (does not happen for me but I have not tried with your file as that requires signing up). MS have a workaround [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/210684) but it seem at least very *similar* to what you have tried.

Other suggestions include (from [WebmasterFacts](http://webmasterfacts.com/runtime-error-1004/)):

```
You need to stop all the programs that are running currently through Task manager
Now go the start menu and you will find control panel over there
Locate Add/ remove programs in there
Now look for ‘Microsoft Works’
When you find it, go ahead and remove it and you are good to go
```

Scanning the whole system is important to confiscate various malwares, corrupt files, viruses, etc. and when the cleanup is done you have to mend the Windows Registry with the repair tool available for Registry. Now when you have done all this you will be able to finally get rid of runtime error 1004.

Alternative Method

```
Right click on the start menu
 You will find Explore option, select that
Once in there  you need to open this directory – C:\Program Files\MSOffice\Office\XLSTART
Here you need to delete “GWXL97.XLA” file
Now open the excel after you have closed the explorer
Your Excel will be running fine without giving any runtime error 1004.
```

Answer (score 0):

I got your point, as the excel sheet are copying empty with Sheet-1 name is that the name of the sheet what you are trying to copy is 30 or 31 character, and Excel do not accept any sheet more than 31 character so this is why it can not be copied properly, please reduce the name of the sheet and try, I am sure you will be able to copy the sheet to an other location.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this might be a valuable hint to solve the problem, a good answer also demonstrates the solution.  Please [edit] to provide example code to show what you mean. Alternatively, consider writing this as a comment instead.